# Undefined offset en PHP

Tags: php, sql

A ver si me podéis ayudar que por muchas vueltas que le doy, no logro encontrar el error. El código que adjunto me devuelve:

> Notice: "Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/16/181528/webspace/httpdocs/sur-madrid.es/alumnos/Richard/Marcas/Administrador/aceptar-edicion.php
>   on line 56 Notice: Undefined index: in
>   /var/www/vhosts/16/181528/webspace/httpdocs/sur-madrid.es/alumnos/Richard/Marcas/Administrador/aceptar-edicion.php
>   on line 56"

Entiendo que el error se produce en la línea 56 (`$sql = "UPDATE marcas SET " . $fila[$i] . " = '" . $_POST[$fila[$i]] . "' WHERE nombre = '" . $marca . "'";`) hasta ahí llego, pero no llego a saber el porqué del fallo, espero que me podáis ayudar, gracias. El código es el siguiente:

```
<body>
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

        // Valor por defecto en PHP
        // Muestra todos los errores menos las notificaciones
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        // Muestro todos los errores
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        error_reporting(-1);

        // Muestro todos los errores, incluso los estrictos
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

        // No muestra ningún error
        error_reporting(0);

        // También se puede usar la función ini_set
        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


     //// Recoger variables ////

    $marca = $_GET['marca'];

    ////Datos db
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $password = "pass";
    $servidor = "server";
    $basededatos = "bd";

    ////Crear conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
    or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Seleccionar db
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
    or die("Uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Establecer y realizar consulta
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM marcas";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    for($i=0; $i<=mysqli_num_fields($resultado); $i++){

        $sql = "UPDATE marcas SET " . $fila[$i] . " = '" . $_POST[$fila[$i]] . "' WHERE nombre = '" . $marca . "'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        }

    ////Cerrar conexion 
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Probablemente for($i=0; $i<=mysqli_num_fields($resultado); $i++){ tiene que ser for($i=0; $i<=mysqli_num_fields($resultado) - 1; $i++){ ya que si hay 5 campos y comienzas en 0, con tu bucle haces 6 vueltas y el índice está fuera de rango.

Comment: estas utilizando `fetch_assoc()` por ende estas haciendo referencia a un conjunto de elementos no solo a 1 con `$fila[$i]`, debes hacer referencia al elemento especifico ejemplo: `$fila[$i]["id"]`

Answer (score 1):

> int mysqli_num_fields ( mysqli_result $result )
>   Retorna el número de campos del resultset especificado.

Por lo tanto, tu error está en este bucle, nunca el índice `$i` puede ser igual al número de campos ya que si hay 3 campos el índice sólo está dentro del rango hasta el número 2 (0,1,2) prueba en usar `<` en vez de `<=`.

```
for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_fields($resultado); $i++){

      $sql = "UPDATE marcas SET " . $fila[$i] . " = '" . $_POST[$fila[$i]] . "' WHERE nombre = '" . $marca . "'";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

}
```

[Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.field-count.php)